# nested ifelse calculations in R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and am finding the nested ifelse functionality does not behave as I would expect.  To begin, some info which is used as an input to my function:

```
loss_cor_df<-data.frame(from_1=c(0,.4,0), to_1=c(0,.5,0), 
                    from_2=c(0,.55,0), to_2=c(0,.65,0),  
                    from_3=c(0,.75,0), to_3=c(0,.85,0) 
                    )

loss_cor_dol<-100*loss_cor_df

loss_cor_rate_df<-data.frame(rate_1=c(0,0.5,0), rate_2=c(0,0.75,0), rate_3=c(0,1,0))
```

My function:

```
apply_lc<- function(x, lc, rate) 
{ifelse(x>=lc$from_3, -rate$rate_1*(min(x,lc$to_1) - lc$from_1) - rate$rate_2*(min(x,lc$to_2)-lc$from_2) - rate$rate_3*(min(x,lc$to_3)-lc$from_3),
ifelse(x>=lc$from_2,  -rate$rate_1*(min(x,lc$to_1) - lc$from_1) - rate$rate_2*(min(x,lc$to_2)-lc$from_2),  
  ifelse(x>=lc$from_1, -rate$rate_1*(min(x,lc$to_1) - lc$from_1),
    0)))
}
```

If I apply this to a scalar, I get the expected result.

```
> apply_lc(85,loss_cor_dol[2,], loss_cor_rate_df[2,])
[1] -22.5
```

However, when I attempt the following, I no longer get the correct answer.

```
> apply_lc(c(85,80),loss_cor_dol[2,], loss_cor_rate_df[2,])
[1] -17.5 -17.5
```

I am able to use for loops and the "other" if...else function.  However, for performance reasons I was hoping to vectorize the operation.  The "apply" family did not seem like it would work as the inputs to the function may vary for every column in my data.  I suspect that I have a fundamental misunderstanding about the way in which R interprets this information and would very much appreciate any asssitance.

Comment: min isn't vectorized so use pmin instead--min will always give you something of length 1 whereas pmin will give you a vector the same length as the inputs (generally)

Comment: btw sorry to be rude but the code is awful. Putting a formula/saying what you want to achieve to help readers (so that they do not have to write down things) would give better understanding for all!